# Why does overloading operator new change the behavior of new[]?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, new-operator

Below is a code snippet run under vs2015:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    A(int _a,int _b){}
    //func1
    void* operator new(size_t sz) {
        cout << "func1"<<endl;
        return malloc(sz);
    }
};
//func2
void* operator new(size_t sz) {
    cout << "func2" << endl;
    return malloc(sz);
}

int main() {
    int* i = new int;//OK,it calls the func2
    int* i1 = new int[6];//why does it call the func2,not the implicit default `operator new[]`?
    A *a = new A(1, 2);//OK,it calls the func1
    A* a1 = new A[2]{ {1,2},{3,4} };//why does it call the func2 instead of func1?
    return 0;
}
```

## Questions:

1. As we know, if we want to change the behavior of `new[]` we just need to define and replace the default `operator new[]`. However, why does overloading `operator new` also change its behavior? **Is such behavior implementation defined or required by the standard?** Is there any way to stop that because I just want the default behavior for `new[]`?
2. Based on question 1, if overloading `operator new` changes `new[]`'s behavior, **why isn't `func1`, but `func2` called in `new A[2]` statement?**

---

## supplement:

From [another code snippet](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), cppref comments `int* p2 = new int[10]; // guaranteed to call the replacement in C++11.` It seems like such behavior is guaranteed in the C++11 standard for the first time.

Comment: IIRC in the global scope, `::new[]` is defined from `::new`, so...

Comment: Yep, look http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new for entry (2): _"The standard library implementation calls version (1)"_

Comment: @YSC So is it implementation defined or required by the standard?

Comment: The former I guess.

Comment: @YSC From one  code snippet in the [linkage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) ,cppref comments `int* p2 = new int[10]; // guaranteed to call the replacement in C++11`. It seems like the behavior is guaranteed since standard  c++11.

Comment: I was wrong ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is such behavior implementation defined or required by the standard?

According to [`[new.delete.array]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/support.dynamic#new.delete.array-4):

> ```
> void* operator new[](std::size_t size);
> ```
>
> *Default behavior*: Returns `operator new(size)`.

By replacing `::new(std::size_t)`, you make `::new[](std::size_t)` call your [custom allocation function](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.allocation). This explains the observed behaviour.

---

> Why isn't `func1`,but `func2` called in `new A[2]` statement?

<s>It seems `new A[x]` default behaviour is to call `::operator new[]`, but I cannot tell why.</s> (This is wrong, see StoryTeller answer).

Comment: But why isn't `A::operator new` called?Does the standard say the default `::operator new[]` must call the `::operator new`,but not the most appropriate one?

Comment: No,it's the `func2` called in `new A[2]` statement.

Comment: @bigxiao I dunno :(

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to complement [@YSC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49980277/817643), and address

> Why isn't `func1`, but `func2` called in `new A[2]` statement?

It's all there in this paragraph:

> [**[expr.new]/9**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#9)
>
> If the *new-expression* begins with a unary `​::`​ operator, the
>   allocation function's name is looked up in the global scope.
>   Otherwise, if the allocated type is a class type `T` or array thereof,
>   the allocation function's name is looked up in the scope of `T`. If this
>   lookup fails to find the name, or if the allocated type is not a class
>   type, the allocation function's name is looked up in the global scope.

So `new A[2]` will start by looking for an appropriate allocation function in the scope of `A`. That function would need to be named `operator new[]`. There is no `A::operator new[]` member, so the lookup fails. The function is then looked up in the global scope. That means `::operator new[]` is found. It's the same allocation function that allocates the array of integers. And like YSC details, it calls `::operator new`, which you displaced. That's why you observe `func2` being called.

Answer (score -1):

'operator new' deals with size -not type- of its operand. The default impl for array form forwards the required size to global 'operator new'. 'operator new' is just a function, not a template or anything. All the magic in size calculation takes place before call to the 'operator new'. In order to make array delete possible, some minor spice is added after the array form returns. Had templates been present when new/delete where introduced to C++, semantics would be much clearer.